# UITableViewHeaderFooterView and Interface Builder: how to adjust width for different devices?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am implementing a custom Header view for my `UITableView`. I created a `HeaderView` class that extends `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and a Nib file for this view.

In the view controller, I registered it:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeaderView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
```

And then set as a header:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  HeaderView *view = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
  return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 26.0f;
}
```

The problem is that the width of the view is always the same as in the nib file. Since now there are multiple screen widths, I cannot simply set the view width to 320 (or the width of the table view) in the nib file.

How exactly am I supposed to set up the header view so it automatically fits the table width?

Update: here's a comparison when I change the view simulated metrics from Inferred to a fixed one (iPhone 3.5" in this case):

[img http://cl.ly/image/451n2N303J3S/Image%202015-04-19%20at%206.39.58%20PM.png](http://cl.ly/image/451n2N303J3S/Image%202015-04-19%20at%206.39.58%20PM.png)

Comment: After initializing `HeaderView` in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`, have you tried setting the `frame`? Something like `view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame), 0)`.

Comment: I checked my own project where I use the same technique as you, and I don't need to manually set the width: if you use auto layout in the NIB file, everything should take care of itself.

Comment: Setting the frame didn't help. In your nib file, what are the simulated metrics for the Size?

Comment: Hm, where can I find that?

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski, in the Attributes Inspector (cmd+opt+4), the first item

Comment: I have `Freeform`, and do the layout on a 320pt view width. When running on the iPad (or other iPhones), it stretches properly.

Comment: What are the subviews in your view tree? Here's what my view looks like: http://cl.ly/image/3S0p1n2n203T/Image%202015-04-19%20at%206.40.44%20PM.png

Comment: Here you go: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/185344/StackOverflow/CustomHeader.png. Do you have layout constraints on both sides?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75661/discussion-between-guilherme-and-marko-nikolovski).

Comment: Here's a small project (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/185344/StackOverflow/TableViewHeaderTest.zip) with a custom header. It's a bit rough, but you see that the text automatically reflows on different iPhones/iPads and when you rotate the device.

Comment: do you mind posting the solution as an answer? I'm having the same problem I couldn't actually follow on the chat

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem ... the only solution I found was by setting all the frames of the subviews in my custom **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** to the according state.

Dirty example:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *headerIdentifier = @"SectionHeader";
    TableViewHeaderFooterView *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:headerIdentifier];
    if (headerView == nil) {
        headerView = [[TableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:headerIdentifier];
    }
    .....
    [headerView setWidthForSubviews:tableView.frame.size.width]; // set the right width of the right subviews
    ....
    return headerView;
}
```

in TableViewHeaderFooterView

```
- (void)setWidthForSubviews:(CGFloat)width {
    for (UIView *view in @[[self viewWithTag:1],[self viewWithTag:2],[self viewWithTag:3], ...]) {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, width, view.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

If someone finds another solution I'll be grateful but it seems that **UITableViewHeaderFooterView** may have problems with autolayout, especially if you load it from a nib.

Comment: this answer solved the problem for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30505729/1471303

Answer (score 0):

I would look at a couple of things.

If you using springs and struts, then trying set the autoResizingMask

```
[maskingBackground setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

If using autolayout then pin to the tableWidth and use a constant height constraint.

If that does not meet your needs I would look at using this in your header view class

```
-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView*)superview
```

And setting your frame in there using the superview.frame.size to guide you.