# Wrong width of custom section header form xib

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I can't manage to make the view's width adapt to the size of the table view on different screen sizes

Here's my code on viewDidLoad()

```
    view.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Header", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")
```

And on the Table View Delegate:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("Header") as! Header
    // etc 
 }
```

Keep in mind that I don't want to put this in a Storyboard and that I am using Auto Layout.

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My xib consisted of a UITableViewCell. I replaced it by a UIView and it solved my problem